# Could not retrieve the change details

Tags: git, gerrit, git-extensions

**Git Extensions** is all setup, the repository can be cloned, commits can be published to **Gerrit**, but it seems that the "**Download Gerrit Change**" button doesn't work as it give me an error saying **Could not retrieve the change details**.

I got all of this working on a previous machine, but now I had to change to a different one and it seems that it stopped working.

Checked all the settings on the 2 machines and they are matching.

The only difference is that the previous machine was on **Windows 8.1** and this one is on **Windows 10** (don't know if this can cause a problem).

Any help would be appreciated.

GitExtension version 2.49
Git version 2.11.1

## [image]

**Edit :** One thing to add here is that previously I was using Windows 8.1 and the new machine has Windows 10 (don't know if that could cause the problem). All of my colleagues that have the same problem are on Windows 10.

Comment: We in our team have the same problem. It works in GitExtensions 2.4.8, but stops working when we upgrade to GitExtensions 2.4.9. You might try to install 2.4.8 and see if that works? We use windows 7 and I have Git 2.8 (don't know the git version for the others)

Comment: Tried to install GitExtensions 2.4.8, but we still get the same problem. The strange thing is that on my previous machine, I had GitExtensions 2.4.8 and it was working fine.

Comment: Seem to be the logged as a bug on github: https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/3530
msysgit issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know exactly at what stage this is supposed to happen, but it seems like the ssh agent is supposed to have some environment variables being set.

GitExtensions is trying to look for the location of the ssh.exe file, but it fails and that's why the error message is thrown.

The **Environment Variables** (to get here, press **WINDOWS KEY + PAUSE** -> **Advanced System Settings** -> **Environment Variables...**) that we need to have are:

**User variables:**

Name: **GIT_SSH**

Value: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe**

**System variables**

Name: **GIT_SSH**

Value: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\usr\bin**

*Note: This is where the ssh agent is in my case (and my colleagues), check where your one is and replace the paths.

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE:**

An even easier way of sorting out this problem is just to go into **GitExtensions** -> **Tools** -> **Settings** -> **SSH** and select **Other ssh client** and specify the location of ssh.exe (in my case it was **C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe**).

Comment: Your solution in the "update" section solves the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some "Gerrit" plugin on GitExtensions? I'm not sure but I think you need to have [git-review](https://github.com/openstack-infra/git-review) installed on your machine or you got the error you have mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I am using a Gerrit plugin, but the thing is this was working perfect before, no problem whatsoever. After changing the machine and getting the versions mentioned above I started to have the problems. All of my colleagues have the same problem after installing these versions as well. With an older version of GitExtenstions and Git, everything was working fine.